# One instance of navigation bar in every tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've been struggling this problem for several days. In my application I have tab bar controller with UINavigationViewControllers inside. I want every navigation bar in every navigation controller to look exactly the same depending on user actions and app state. 
For example: if user logged in to my app in first view controller, app sets his name in navigation bar and sets navigation bar into logged in state. Then when user selects other tab item, I want to set this logged in state of navigation bar from first view controller to other view controllers. I've tried to use singleton but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to do 2 things:

1. Set the current settings while init the `UIViewController`
2. Update all initiated Controllers after state changes

to 1:
create a class with

```
@interface UIViewController (UINavigationController)

- (UINavigationController*)wrapWithNavigationController;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (UINavigationController)

- (UINavigationController*)wrapWithNavigationController
{
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];

    // your customizations
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    [...]

    return [navigationController autorelease];
}

@end
```

you can call it `UIViewControllerAdditions` for example.

to 2:

use the [NSNotificationCenter](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/16/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial-using-the-notification-center-in-your-iphone-app/) for updates :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have multiple `UINavigationControllers`, or do you just want to use the `navigationBar` for the same actions and functionality in every tab?

If you just want to have the bar, you could also use an `UINavigationController` as your apps `rootViewController` and then the `UITabBarController` as a `childViewController` of your `UINavigationController`.